# Using automapper profiles to map 2 different types into one

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to map (using AutoMapper) two different objects into the same object, and how?

Below is an example to describe the case (keep in mind that it's a conceptual example):

```
namespace AutomapperTest.Profiles
{
    public class CarWrapper
    {
        public CarWrapper(Car car, string customerName)
        {
            CustomerName = customerName;
            Car = car;
        }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarView
    {
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Serial { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarProfile : Profiles
    {
        public CarProfile()
        {
            // Map profile of Car with specific add-ons from CarWrapper
            CreateMap<CarWrapper, CarView>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Customer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName))
                .ForMember(dst => dst, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Car)); // <-- This will throw an exception.

            // Map profile of Car
            CreateMap<Car, CarView>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Model, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ModelName))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Serial, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

What I wish to do is to tell the first CreateMap to use another CreateMap for the nested type of the parent:

```
.ForMember(dst => dst, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Car));
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Unfortunately that link doesn't tell me how I setup the profiles to fullfill the request. Please look at the two different map configs, where one is the dependent on the other one.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Look at the source ( .ForMember(dst => dst, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Car)); // <-- This will throw an exception.). The issue here is, that I want to have the profile for mapping Car->CarView explicit, and use that mapping in the profile of CarWrapper -> CarView, together with a few other rules explicit used in the CarWrapper.

Comment: That's not possible, the closest thing is flattening. You can also call Map twice by passing an existing destination. I'm sure there are other ways, but not _exactly_ what you want.

Comment: You can make CarWrapper derive from Car and use Include.